# Issues with strpos inside while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, strpos

My question is mainly about a "while condition" that apparently returns "TRUE" when in shuld return "FALSE". This is the code:

```
<?php
$sentence='is is is';
$search='is';
$length=strlen($search);
$offset=0;
$j=1;
while(($pos = strpos($sentence,$search,$offset)) !==FALSE)
{
 echo $j.'. '.$pos.'<br>';
 $offset += $length;
 $j++;
}
?>
```

which returns:

> 1. 0
> 2. 3
> 3. 6

Fist result's display proves to be 0 which is FALSE? Why was the code within the "while loop" operated all the same?

Comment: Because `0 !== FALSE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fist result's display proves to be 0 which is FALSE

I think you are misundertanding 0 is the position of the first occurrence of `is` and not the boolean 0

```
$sentence='is is is';
           ^  ^  ^
           0  3  6
```

Comment: I think I misunderstood !== operator...

Comment: does my answer clarifiy or should I expand further

Comment: All answers I recieved here gave me a very clear answer about not fully understanding the operator's role in my loop.